# excel formula for time and converting it to time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns of times: column A has start time, column B has end time. I want to know how I can view this with this formula:

```
=IF(AND($C3<=E$2,D$3>=E$2),1,0)
```

I'd like to fill the cell with 1 if the hour is covered.

Here is a screen shot of what im trying to do:
[image]

Comment: `D$3` should be `$D3`

Comment: Are those actual times, in the column or are they text? click on one of the cells with a time in it and then change the cell format to general.  If nothing changes or its already set to general, then your time is actually Text.  you can also test with formula `=ISNUMBER(A4)` where A4 is a cell containing one of your times.  IF it comes back as false then your time is actually text.  Your proposed formula only works if those times are numbers and not text.  Also be careful of the end times that are actually the following day.